# Return metrics ranking in r

Tags: r

The subset of the data is as follows:

```
Cat <- c('A','B','C')
Metrics1 <- c(1,4,3)
Metrics2 <- c(1.5,0.3,3.4)
Metrics3 <- c(0.1,40,3.2)
df <- data.frame(Cat,Metrics1,Metrics2,Metrics3)
```

I want to create another data frame in such a way that for each category I get rankings of the metrics(Min Value of a metrics makes its rank as 1),

The sample output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n_metrics <- 3

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Metrics1, Metrics2, Metrics3), names_to = "Metrics") %>%
  group_by(Cat) %>% arrange(Cat,value) %>%
  mutate(Performance = paste0("Best-",1:n_metrics)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Cat, Performance, Metrics)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   Cat [3]
  Cat   Performance Metrics 
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>   
1 A     Best-1      Metrics3
2 A     Best-2      Metrics1
3 A     Best-3      Metrics2
4 B     Best-1      Metrics2
5 B     Best-2      Metrics1
6 B     Best-3      Metrics3
7 C     Best-1      Metrics1
8 C     Best-2      Metrics3
9 C     Best-3      Metrics2
```

This approach will work as long as you have three MetricScores. If you need more you need to adjust **n_metrics**.

First we use **tidyr::pivot_longer** to make your dataframe *longer*.
Then we group by **Cat** and arrange values accordingly (default is increasing).
Then we add Performance measure (as Metrics are already sorted).